# Correct way to use ResourceManager in a multi-threaded environment in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, localization

So, I currently hold an instance of the ResourceManager in a static variable accessible for all classes in my solution. I've used it for getting translation stuff for single-threaded operation and it was working just fine and dandy.

However, I then added an operation that takes a bit longer to execute, and I need to update the progress in the UI. For the progress information strings, I also use the ResourceManager. Thing is, the same exact line of code returns null (Localization.ResourceManager.GetString("ProgressInformation1"), for example) if it is executed on a separate thread. But if I don't fire a new thread for it, it returns the string as expected. I checked the MSDN library, and according to it, ResourceManager should be thread-safe and all. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates the issue please.

Comment: Maybe the `CurrentUICulture` of the other thread is different from the original's, and the string is not defined for the fallback culture?

Comment: It indeed was as simple as not setting the new thread's culture. The bit that's surprising to me is that I thought one of the two languages I currently support was indeed the fallback one, but I guess not :) Care to make an answer of this so I can choose it?

Comment: Well, there's not much to elaborate upon, and Alexey's answer is already there, so... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to specify CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture for the thread you run.
Just use ones from the "main" thread.

Comment: I think you should write this as a comment, not an answer.